# How can I tell if my website is vulnerable to CVE-2014-3566 (POODLE)?

Tags: security, https

Google [announced](http://googleonlinesecurity.blogspot.com/2014/10/this-poodle-bites-exploiting-ssl-30.html) a vulnerability in the SSLv3 protocol that

> ... allows the plaintext of secure connections to be calculated by a network attacker.

This vulnerability has been given the designation [CVE-2014-3566](http://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2014-3566) and the marketing name POODLE.

If I have a website at `https://www.example.com/, how can I tell if this vulnerability affects me?

Answer (score 17):

## SSLv3 is Broken

With the advent of POODLE, all the cipher suites used by SSLv3 have been compromised, and the protocol should be considered irreparably broken.

### Websites

You can check if your website is available over SSLv3 with [`curl(1)`](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html):

```
curl -v -3 -X HEAD https://www.example.com
```

The `-v` argument turns on verbose output, `-3` forces curl to use SSLv3, and the `-X HEAD` limits the output on a successful connection.

If you are not vulnerable, you should not be able to connect, and your output should look something like this:

```
* SSL peer handshake failed, the server most likely requires a client certificate to connect
```

If you are vulnerable, you should see normal connection output, including the line:

```
* SSL 3.0 connection using SSL_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL
```

### Other Services

It's not just websites that are available over SSL. Mail, irc, and LDAP are three examples of services available via secured connections, and are similarly vulnerable to POODLE when they accept SSLv3 connections.

To connect to a service using SSLv3, you can use the [`openssl(1)`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/openssl.html) [`s_client(1)`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/s_client.html) command:

```
openssl s_client -connect imap.example.com:993 -ssl3 < /dev/null
```

The `-connect` argument takes a `hostname:port` parameter, the `-ssl3` argument limits the protocol versions negotiated to SSLv3, and piping in `/dev/null` to `STDIN` immediately terminates the connection after opening it.

If you connect successfully, SSLv3 is enabled; if you get a `ssl handshake failure` then it is not.

### See Also

There is an excellent question and answer on the Security SE: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/70719/ssl3-poodle-vulnerability

Comment: It's not clear to me that `curl`'s `-v` flag takes an argument; can you confirm what you wrote above?  Or if that requires a particular version of `curl`, that would be useful to know also.

Comment: @MadHatter: No, that's two arguments -v and -3 combined into one.  It does look like "v3" though.

Comment: Thanks, the clarification is much appreciated!  I take it almost anything of the form `SSL .*connection using .*_WITH_.*` equates to failure?

Comment: @MadHatter sorry for the confusion, I've updated the answer to be more clear.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do a quick check, head on to the URL below. It does a pretty good job keeping up with all things SSL, including checking for POODLE.

https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/

Comment: While the link may have useful info, links do break making this useless to future visitors.  Adding more info from the link could improve this answer